# Mips polynomial multiplication

Tags: assembly, mips, polynomials, mars-simulator

I am doing a multiplication of polynomials on MIPS using the formula R[i+j] += P[i] * Q[j].

Now, the result I should be getting for R should be  `6 7 15 -10 17 -15`. However, what I'm getting is  `6 7 9 -19 17 -15`, is there something wrong in the way I add numers? what can I do to fix these two wrong values?

```
.data
    P: .word 2, 3, 4, -5
    Q: .word 3, -1, 3
    R: .space 1024  
    m: .asciiz " "
.text
main:
    la $s0, R
    addi $t0, $zero, 0  #outer index
    addi $t2, $zero, 0  #inner index

outer:
beq $t0, 4, outer_exit          #while t0 < 16:

sll $t3, $t0, 2             #$t3 = 4 * i 
lw $t1, P($t3)              #current P value ($t1 = P[$t3])

addi $t0, $t0, 1            #i++
    
move $t2, $zero             #restart $t2 to 0
    inner:
    beq $t2, 3, inner_exit      #while $t2 < 12:
    
    sll $t4, $t2, 2         #$t4 = 4 * j
    
    addi $t2, $t2, 1        #j++

    lw $t5, Q($t4)          #current Q value ($t5 = P[$t4])
    
    mul $t6, $t1, $t5       #$t6 = P[i] * Q[j]
    add $t7, $t3, $t4       #$t7 = i + j
    
    lw $t8, R($t7)
    
    sw $t6, R($t7)          #store $t6 on R[$t7]
    add $t8, $t8, $t6
    
    j inner
    inner_exit:
    
    j outer
outer_exit:
    li  $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: You can't possibly be getting a `7` since no two values multiply to that. Also you realize the `R[i+j]`  does not uniquely determine `i` and `j`. Did you maybe mean `R[i+j] += P[i] * Q[j]`? PS: are you using delay slots? The `add $t8, $t8, $t6` seems to indicate so.

Comment: @Jester I changed += to =, my typo while writing the formula. However the code does do the step correctly. 

Also of course I can get 7: -2 (gotten by multiplying 2 * (-1)) + 9 (gotten by multiplying 3 * 3) = 7.

Comment: You need to move the `addi $t2, $zero, 0` into the outer loop so the inner loop starts from zero every time. You need to move `add $t8, $t8, $t6` before the `sw` which itself should be fixed to write `$t8` not `$t6`. With those changes it works here.

Comment: @Jester Thanks! I already had `addi $t2, $zero, 0` into the outer loop so it worked well, but I did the other two changes you told me and now it's working as I wanted. Have a good day!